# VSCode: How to stop the output window from showing itself during an Angular build?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode, latest version. And I don't want to see the output window when compiling my angular application.

Does anybody know how to disable the auto pop up of the output window?

Answer (score 2):

How are you compiling your program? If you are using a "task" then you can set the `presentation.reveal` configuration setting.

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior):

> reveal: Controls whether the Integrated Terminal panel is brought to
>   front. Valid values are:
>
> - always - The panel is always brought to front. This is the default.
> - never - The user must explicitly bring the terminal panel to the front using the View > Integrated Terminal command (Ctrl+`).
>     *silent - The terminal panel is brought to front only if the output is not scanned for errors and warnings.

That means you would use something like this in your `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            // your task information
            ...
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never" // or silent to only show if there are errors
            }
        }        
    ]
}
```

If you aren't using tasks, then please update the question to give more information about how you are building angular.